# Styling website for different screen sizes with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, typo3, wcag2.0

I am using the following method to style my website for different screen sizes.

```
<div id="sidebar" class="col-md-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <!-- Inner Classes and Stuff -->
    <!-- IMPORTANT: Div auto-inserted by Typo3 -->
</div>  <!-- sidebar -->

<div id="sidebar_mobile" class="col-xs-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <!-- Inner Classes and Stuff -->
    <!-- IMPORTANT: Div auto-inserted by Typo3 -->
</div>  <!-- sidebar -->
```

I then define different styles that I need for #sidebar and #sidebar_mobile in my CSS. This leads to two problems:

- Repetition (there are many shared properties between #sidebar and #sidebar_mobile).
- Duplicate IDs - The divs that are automatically inserted by Typo3 (Raw HTML content inserted via Typo3 backend) end up having the same ID (inside #sidebar and #sidebar_mobile). This fails WCAG 2.0 AA and I need my website to pass this.

I would like to know if there is a better way of going about things in this case. What would be a better solution

Comment: I created a little tool to automagically add screen size classes (xs sm md lg xl) to elements so you can actually style your elements like that without caring about media query pixels or recompiling bootstrap css: stackoverflow.com/a/46654262/263533

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you using two different wrappers for mobile/desktop instead using CSS to style them individually:

```
<div id="sidebar" class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
    <!-- Inner Classes and Stuff -->
    <!-- IMPORTANT: Div auto-inserted by Typo3 -->
</div>
```

```
#sidebar {
    /* Mobile/Tablet styles (xs, sm) */
}
@media (min-width: 991px) {
    #sidebar {
        /* Tablet/Desktop styles (md, lg) */
    }
}
```

This is the mobile first variant.